# Boolean Union not removing intersecting geometries?

Tags: modifiers

I need to merge a few objects and remove the resulting internal meshes/geometry, to be able to 3D print it as a single object. I'm pretty new to Blender but I understanded that Boolean Union should do the job, right? Well, for me it's not :( I'm using Blender 2.92 and this is the result of the Boolean Union:

[image: ,]

The red highlighted portion is inside the arm, and it's what needs to be removed.

Any help would be highly appreciated :(

Comment: I see that your meshes are extremely dense. did you make sure they are manifold (=watertight) ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, that's the point, they are at least until I merge them, the highlighted piece is the arm's pin which goes inside the bust's cavity for better assembling. When I merge the arm and the bust the pin and cavity just stay there, they are not erased.